# ZF3: SharedEventManager injection in EventManager

Tags: zend-framework, dependency-injection, zend-framework3

In ZF2, an event was shared across multiple controllers using a shared event manager

**Module.php**

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $services = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

        $sharedEventManager->attach('user', 'log-fail', function($event) use ($services) {
            $username = $event->getParam('username');
            $log = $services->get('log');
            $log->warn('Error logging user: ' . $username);
        });
    }
}
```

**LogController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManager;

class LogController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function inAction()
    {
        //...
        if (! $isValid) {
            $event = new EventManager('user');
            $event->trigger('log-fail', $this, array('username'=> $username));
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

But ZF3 requires that the shared event manager be injected at instantiation, instead of via a setter.
https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-eventmanager/migration/changed/

So I created a log controller factory to inject the shared event manager but I can't find how to do the injection

**LogControllerFactory.php**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class LogControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $sharedEventManager = ???

        return new LogController($sharedEventManager);
    }
}
```

Would you have any idea on how to get the shared event manager instanced to inject it in the controller in order to get it in the controller __construct function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To answer my own question:**

**1. config.php**

The config file

```
/..
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\LogController::class => Controller\LogControllerFactory::class,
        /..
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'log' => Controller\LogController::class,
        /..
    ]
],
/..
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'log' => Service\Log::class,
    ],
],
/..
```

**2. Module.php**

The module file

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        // Get shared service manager
        $services = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

        // Attach listener
        $sharedEventManager->attach('user', 'log-fail', function($event) use ($services) {
            $username = $event->getParam('username');
            $log = $services->get('log');
            $log->warn('Error logging user: ' . $username);
        });
    }
}
```

**3. LogService.php**

The service file

```
namespace Application\Service;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Log\Logger;
use Zend\Log\Writer\Stream as StreamWriter;
use Zend\Log\Filter\Priority as PriorityFilter;

class Log implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $controllerPluginManager = $container;
        $serviceManager = $controllerPluginManager->get('ServiceManager');

        // Instantiate Zend\Log\Logger
        $log = new Logger();
        // Set stream to write in a log file
        $writer = new StreamWriter('data/logs/audit.log');
        $log->addWriter($writer);

        return $log;
    }
}
```

**4. LogControllerFactory.php***

The controller factory file

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class LogControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $controllerPluginManager = $container;
        $eventManager = $controllerPluginManager->get('EventManager');
        $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

        return new LogController($sharedEventManager);
    }
}
```

**5. LogController.php**

The controller file

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManager;
use Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManager;

class LogController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function __construct(SharedEventManager $sharedEventManager)
    {
        $this->_sharedEventManager = $sharedEventManager;
    }

    public function inAction()
    {
        //...
        if (! $isValid) {
            $event = new EventManager($this->_sharedEventManager, ['user']);
            $event->trigger('log-fail', $this, array('username'=> $username));
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Just a small hint from me: Place the `onBootstrap` Module code in it's own `LogListener` (or something) class. Separates the concerns nicely. Register a Listener in `'service_manager' => ['factories' => [Listener::class => ListenerFactory::class]],` and register a listener under the config root key `'listeners => [Listener::class],` (this last bit makes sure they're registered and used).

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try this.